# Can we push Azure blob data to Tableau hyper file in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to push my blob csvs,parquets to Tableau .Generally Tableau hyperfiles we would be creating in Tableau.

I dont find any connector for Tableau.

Is there any other way to do it via python code or something ?

Comment: I dont want to push it to sql and consume from sql via Tableau. I need to push directly to Tableau .

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, but you can take these files directly from your Data Lake gen2 or other sources supported by Tableaus own ODBC connectors. From my Tableau I can see these options:

[image]

Regarding the hyper data format, I have found a few sources, maybe you can run some python code inside an azure function to convert them to hyper files. Links mention Hyper API

https://medium.com/@elliottstam/hey-kaustubh-yes-you-can-convert-a-csv-file-into-a-hyper-extract-e2da11a41fc7

https://gist.github.com/divinorum-webb/3bdafdeb5348e143676d3b4f26545b02

Converting to .hyper files inside Azure should not be a problem. But I do not know how to transfer a .hyper file directly from Azure into Tableau, you might have to use at least one intermediary such as Data Lake.